# Php - System function - /usr/bin/echo Hello : No such file or directory

Tags: php, linux

I'm a newbie to PhP.
When I run a linux terminal command using `System` function in php, I'm getting errors in `error_log`.
Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
{
    $name=$_POST['User_name']; // here $name contains 'John'
    echo '<pre>';

    $command="/usr/bin/echo $name";
    $command1="'".$command."'";
    $last_line = system($command1, $retval);

    echo '</pre>
    <hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
    <hr />Return value: ' . $retval;        
 }
```

When I run this code, I'm getting the following errors:

```
in browser - giving code : 127  


in /var/log/httpd/error_log file - sh: /usr/bin/echo John: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing anything?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved like this error with the help of `escapeshellarg()`
Here is Updated code..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_button']))
{
    $name=$_POST['User_name']; // here $name contains 'John'
    echo '<pre>';

    $last_line = system('/usr/bin/echo'.escapeshellarg($name));  
                                      // here escapeshellarg() does the trick

    echo '</pre>
    <hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
    <hr />Return value: ' . $retval;  
}
```

Thank you all for your immediate response.

Answer (score 0):

Try with only echo, and not with /usr/bin/echo
Change your command variable declaration as follow :

```
$command="echo $name";
```

Comment: Because you are running $commmand1 which is enclosed by single quotes which considered as a string instead of command. Remove the line $command1="'".$command."'"; And try with $last_line = system($command, $retval);

Answer (score 0):

```
$command="/usr/bin/echo $name";
```

You just want to add the value of the $name variable to the path right? If so just write this as

```
$command="/usr/bin/$name";
```

php will parse variables in strings between double qoutes, see [string.parsing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)